# UndefinedError: 'request' is undefined in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am using Django 3.1. I have a template view that usually renders fine, however on occasion I find the following error in my logs. Unfortunately I can't seem to reproduce it.

```
UndefinedError: 'request' is undefined
  File "django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "django/core/handlers/base.py", line 106, in _get_response
    response = middleware_method(request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs)
  File "django/middleware/csrf.py", line 242, in process_view
    return self._reject(request, REASON_NO_REFERER)
  File "django/middleware/csrf.py", line 149, in _reject
    response = _get_failure_view()(request, reason=reason)
  File "django/views/csrf.py", line 154, in csrf_failure
    return HttpResponseForbidden(t.render(c), content_type='text/html')
  File "django_jinja/backend.py", line 59, in render
    return mark_safe(self._process_template(self.template.render, context, request))
  File "django_jinja/backend.py", line 105, in _process_template
    return handler(context)
  File "scout_apm/instruments/jinja2.py", line 74, in wrapped_render
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "jinja2/environment.py", line 1090, in render
    self.environment.handle_exception()
  File "jinja2/environment.py", line 832, in handle_exception
    reraise(*rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source))
  File "jinja2/_compat.py", line 28, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/app/templates/403_csrf.html", line 8, in top-level template code
    {% set card_body %}
  File "/app/templates/global/base_tenant.html", line 2, in top-level template code
    {% extends 'global/base.html' %}
  File "/app/templates/global/base.html", line 4, in top-level template code
    {% block header %}
  File "/app/templates/global/base.html", line 26, in block "header"
    <link nonce="{{ request.csp_nonce }}" rel="manifest" href="{{ static('manifest.json') }}">
  File "jinja2/environment.py", line 471, in getattr
    return getattr(obj, attribute)
```

This appears to be an issue with the `request` variable not being in the context variable, however I thought Django always delivers `request` to template without exception?

Comment: Is `django.template.context_processors.request` in your context processors? This needs to be added if you want `request` in every template. More info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext)

Comment: Yes, my first thought was this, but it is set correctly. Could it be `request.csp_nonce`  is not in the context, but `request` is?